# Add custom field to paypal module magento 1.9

Tags: xml, magento, paypal, magento-1.9

I need to add an extra field to paypal configuration, but due to "infinite" groups used in papal configuration i have no way to add it. Is it possible to add a custom field to core paypal v.1.6.0.6 magento 1.9 module?

I'm trying with the below code in my custom module's system.xml file, but no luck. The cashondelivery option in the same xml works fine.

Any help will be appreciated

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <paypal_payments>
                    <payments_pro_hosted_solution translate="label comment">
                        <fields>
                            <pphs_required_settings translate="label">
                                <fields>
                                    <pphs_required_settings_pphs translate="label">
                                        <fields>
                                            <charge_type translate="label">
                                                <label>Payment Charge Type</label>
                                                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                                <source_model>paymentcharge/system_config_source_chargetype</source_model>
                                                <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                            </charge_type>
                                            <charge_value translate="label">
                                                <label>Payment Charge</label>
                                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                                <sort_order>24</sort_order>
                                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                            </charge_value>
                                        </fields>
                                    </pphs_required_settings_pphs>
                                </fields>
                            </pphs_required_settings>
                        </fields>
                    </payments_pro_hosted_solution>
                </paypal_payments>
                <cashondelivery translate="label">
                    <fields>
                        <charge_type translate="label">
                            <label>Payment Charge Type</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>paymentcharge/system_config_source_chargetype</source_model>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </charge_type>
                        <charge_value translate="label">
                            <label>Payment Charge</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>201</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </charge_value>
                    </fields>
                </cashondelivery>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

And here the official paypal module v 1.6.0.6 for magento 1.9 system.xml file

https://github.com/mgtf/magento-1.9.2.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/system.xml

Comment: can you tell me in which paypal method you want to add extra field? In admin there is option for paypal like paypal pro,paypal link etc

Comment: @Jinesh i want to add it to Website Payments Plus and Payments Standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <paypal_payments>
                    <payments_pro_hosted_solution translate="label comment">
                        <fields>
                            <pphs_required_settings translate="label">
                                <fields>
                                    <pphs_required_settings_pphs translate="label">
                                    <label>Payments Pro Hosted Solution</label>
                                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                        <frontend_model>paypal/adminhtml_system_config_fieldset_expanded</frontend_model>
                                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                        <fields>
                                            <charge_type translate="label">
                                                <label>Payment Charge Type</label>
                                                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                                <source_model>paymentcharge/system_config_source_chargetype</source_model>
                                                <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                            </charge_type>
                                            <charge_value translate="label">
                                                <label>Payment Charge</label>
                                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                                <sort_order>24</sort_order>
                                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                            </charge_value>
                                        </fields>
                                    </pphs_required_settings_pphs>
                                </fields>
                            </pphs_required_settings>
                        </fields>
                    </payments_pro_hosted_solution>
                </paypal_payments>
                <cashondelivery translate="label">
                    <fields>
                        <charge_type translate="label">
                            <label>Payment Charge Type</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>paymentcharge/system_config_source_chargetype</source_model>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </charge_type>
                        <charge_value translate="label">
                            <label>Payment Charge</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>201</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </charge_value>
                    </fields>
                </cashondelivery>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: Welcome anytime for help